# How do I store a multidimensional in a flashdata session in codeigniter using CodeIgniter Version 2.x.x

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-2

I want to save data from a multidimensional array into a flashdata session in codeigniter 2.x

```
foreach($value->result as $val){}
    if($val->somethinghappenedtrue){
        $arr[] = array('data' => $thethingthathappened);
    }
}
$this->session->set_flashdata($arr);
```

the arrays would be

```
[0]
    'data' => 'thing1'
[1]
    'data' => 'thing2'
[3]
    'data' => 'thing3'
[4]
    'data' => 'thing4'
```

i have been trying to access is by

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->session->flashdata('arr'));
echo "</pre>";
```

and

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($this->session->flashdata('data'));
echo "</pre>";
```

so that it would print the exact same arrays that are shown above but nothing is displayed on screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  foreach($value->result as $val){}
       if($val->somethinghappenedtrue){
           $arr[] = $thethingthathappened;
       }
   }
   $this->session->set_flashdata('data',$arr);

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($this->session->flashdata('data'));
   echo "</pre>";
```

It will give you result as following

Array
(
    [0] => thing1
    [1] => thing2
    [2] => thing3
)